# How to use Generic Types with Lodash Get?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, lodash

Using lodash's `get` with generic types to type the return object. However, the type doesn't make sense. In the example below, I cannot supply `test` to the first param because it is supposed to be `null | undefined`

The use of `get()` is that you can get a value of an object without knowing if it exists or not. So I would expect the type to be an explicit `any`. If I knew that it was `null | undefined` then I wouldn't try and get a key from that object

**example.ts**

```
const test = {
  a: false
};

const example = get<boolean>(test, "a", true);
```

**@types/lodash**

```
get(object: null | undefined, path: PropertyPath): undefined;
```

**ts error**

```
Argument of type '{ a: boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'null | undefined'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first generic is not the return value, it's the input value. With your example, it's saying the input is a `boolean` (or `null` or `undefined`).

If you remove it entirely it should work:

```js
const test = {
  a: false
};

const example = get(test, "a", true);
```

Looking at [all of the type definitions for `get` with objects](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/lodash/common/object.d.ts#L1657) they all have `TObject` as the first generic: `get<TObject extends object, ...>`